# Java testing if two void methods do the same

Tags: java, testing, void

I have a class of paired void methods: each method has an equivalent one that should perform the same operation but in a different way.
For example:

```
public void example1_1(){
    Integer i = new Integer(1);
}

public void example1_2(){
    Integer i = Integer.valueOf(11);
}
```

or

```
public void example2_1(){
    String result = "hello";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        result += result;
    }
}

public void example2_2(){
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer("hello");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        result += result;
    }
}
```

How can I test that the methods **actually** perform the same operations in pair?

Comment: From a theoratical point of view, it is undecidable if two programs calculate the same function (in general). And your example function don't _do_ anything than wasting time. There is no result that is returned or any other side effect.

Comment: You can't track what was performed by a method and was it similar to another method since you have no result. The "result" of work of both your methods aren't stored anywhere, therefore you can't predict they were really performed. Compiler might even throw them away from bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you don't have any return value. That seems to be as planned.

It's very hard to define 'methods that do the same', are you considering the result only - if so, why 'void' and not just checking the return value? Do you mean performance wise? complexity wise? there are many levels of 'the same'-ness you could ask for.

If you want to verify that some method was called N times over the iteration, you can use Mockito verify method - for example - that myMethod() was called only a single time.

```
verify(myClass, times(1)).myMethod();
```

I'd strongly suggest you to use the return value to verify the result is the same.

In more wide approach, one could argue that part of OOP programming and interface approach in specific is that it doesn't really matter of **how** the method does what it does, **as long as it does it correctly**, i.e. as long as the method returns what it should, the inner implementation is irrelevant.
You could check the correctness using unit testing, like I suggested before, use the return value and many unit tests to verify the correctness of various inputs